# how to force JavaScript form Validation before making request to server?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have tried the following code to implement the javaScript validation for the form. When someone just hit the `Sign Up` button without any input then the div tag shows the `Enter Your First Name` in the browser.  That is just what I supposed it to do. However, when someone hits the `Sign Up` twice without input the function is not invoked but sends to the server.

I wonder what changes are to be made in the code below to make sure that user is forced to  input something before sending it to server. Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 <script language="javascript">
            var flag=0;
            function firstname()
            {
                firstname=join.firstname.value;
                if(firstname=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById("errorFname").innerHTML="Enter Your First Name";
                    flag=1;

                }   
              }
      function check(form)
            {
                flag=0;
                firstname();

                if(flag==1)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
    </script>

       <form id= "join"  class="form-signUp" name="join" action="http://cs-sun2000.uscupstate.edu/~student1/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" method= "post" onSubmit="return check(this)">

        <div id="errorFname"></div><br><input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onBlur="firstname()" >
<button  name="submit" type="submit" >Sign Up</button>
        </form>
```

[image: this is what I see on browser]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the firstname variable, first asign to a function, is then reused to receive the input value.

When input is null, the firstname variable is set to null, and your console shows an error.
You just need to change the function name, or the string variable name.

**--- EDIT --**

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LBne/)

```
var valid;
function checkFirstname() {
  var firstname =join.firstname.value;
  if(!firstname || firstname.trim().length === 0) {
     document.getElementById("errorFname").innerHTML="Enter Your First Name";
     valid=false;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("errorFname").innerHTML="";
  }
}

function check(form) {
  valid=true;
  checkFirstname();
  return valid;
}
```

I prefer to check the firstname existence: it will fail if firstname is null.
Then I check the length after a trim: it will fail if the user just put spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ondblclick event like `ondblclick="myFunction()"` of button tag.

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd like to use jQuery, this is a nice alternative, with [jQueryValidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org):

```
<form id="commentForm" method="post" action="http://cs-sun2000.uscupstate.edu/~student1/cgi-bin/echo.cgi">
    <label for="cfirstname">Enter your first name:</label>
    <em>*</em><input id="cfirstname" name="firstname" size="25" />
</form>

<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate({
      rules: {
       firstname: "required"
      }
    });
   });
 </script>
```